qiskit.exceptions.QiskitError: 'Invalid input data for Pauli.'
I have some old version qiskit==0.46 code which uses an API as below:
from qiskit.opflow import MatrixOp
H_op = MatrixOp(Hamiltonian).to_pauli_op() 

After much study, I tried to replace it latest qiskit==1.0 API, which has the below syntax:
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
 H_op = SparsePauliOp(Hamiltonian).to_operator()

But this is not correct. It gives me some error : qiskit.exceptions.QiskitError: 'Invalid input data for Pauli.'
It would be great if I can be helped on this.
Edit1
Question updated with the Hamiltonian.
(Pdb) Hamiltonian
array([[ 4.07981221, -3.6713615 ,  1.3943662 , -1.05164319],
       [-3.6713615 ,  5.88262911, -4.14084507,  1.37558685],
       [ 1.3943662 , -4.14084507,  5.83098592, -3.54929577],
       [-1.05164319,  1.37558685, -3.54929577,  3.79812207]])


what is your Hamiltonian in the code?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about quantum computing (for the same reason that a question about an exception raised by a legacy biopython API is not a question about biology).

Thank you for the response @EthanDavies. Question updated with Hamiltonian

You can construct a SparsePauliOp from an array using from_operator method as follows:
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp

Hamiltonian = [
    [ 4.07981221, -3.6713615 ,  1.3943662 , -1.05164319],
    [-3.6713615 ,  5.88262911, -4.14084507,  1.37558685],
    [ 1.3943662 , -4.14084507,  5.83098592, -3.54929577],
    [-1.05164319,  1.37558685, -3.54929577,  3.79812207]
]

op = SparsePauliOp.from_operator(Hamiltonian)
print(op)

Internally, this method employs the approach outlined in "Tensorized Pauli decomposition algorithm" by Hantzko, Binkowski, and Gupta, which is more efficient - and more complex - than the method mentioned in @Ethan Davies answer.

Thank you @Egretta.Thula for great great help.

The Hamiltonian should be an iterable collection of  tuples of Pauli's strings and the coefficients, like  H= [('II', 2),('XX',3),('XZ',9)] for the Hamiltonian 2II + 3XX + 9XZ.
To get the coefficients of the Hamiltonian in this form, you can use the trick $H=\sum_i \alpha_i P_i$ where $\alpha_i = tr(HP_i)$.

Thank you for the response @EthanDavies. I need some API so that I can migrate the code to the latest version of qiskit==1.0.
